# Build Failure while integrating Jenkins with HP ALM

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-plugins, alm, hp-alm

Created a Build for running Selenium Maven Scripts through jenkins and publish Results in HP ALM.
Steps I follow:-
1.Add ALM ServerName and ALM URL under Configure System>> Manage Jenkins
2.Add Build Step>> Execute HP Functional Tests from HPALM
Added the test Set Value as Root\TestSet\TestSetFolder
3.Add Post Build Action>>Publish HP Tests Result>> Reports archive Mode
4.Add>>Upload Test Result to ALM
Testing Frameowrk = Junit, Test Folder = "TestSet\TestSetFolder\TestCaseName ,Test Set Folder = "TestSet\TestSetFolder, Testing result file ="**/junitResult.xml
5. Run the Build and getting the Failure whereas my particular selenium scripts get passed. Below is the Error for Console Output.

[image]

Comment: It looks like the addon is not able to locate the folder you want to write in for the QC ALM. The Error: folder   cannot be found in ALM. There are couple of space and looks like you are looking for "Nothing". Have you checked on that?

Comment: @Marcosmdm  " like you are looking for "Nothing" ":- What are you trying to say here. I have entered the ALm Folder Path without spaces.

Comment: if you look at the line "Error: folder _(folderName)_ cannot be found in ALM." There is a double space and I was thinking maybe the tool is failing for that. Nothing means that maybe the folder was not specified. Usually if I print an error in code I would also mentione the folder name...exactly where the two spaces are visible. Maybe this is the issue....but honestly I don't know :) Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, that was because of "\" which were escaped by Jenkins. I don't why. If you remove them and always have a bad path you should have a trace like that :

```
Run mode is set to: RUN_PLANNED_HOST
Could not find TestSet Subject/Scenario/BAD_PATH/TEST_SET
================================================
Run status: Job failed, total tests: 0, succeeded: 0, failures: 0, errors: 0
================================================
Build step 'Execute HPE functional tests from HPE ALM' changed build result to FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

Personnaly I solved the problem replacing "\" by "\\".